# Userform variables to E-mail

Tags: vba, listview, variables, arguments, userform

I have a Userform which has 3 buttons on it and based on the click the respective text needs to be inserted in the body of the email, for this e-mail the To, CC, Subject, will be taken from Listview box in Sheet1 which inturn extracts the values stored in Sheet2 and paste it in To, CC, Subject of the email.

When i paste the code in the buttonclick () command the variables are not getting passed from the maincode to the userform code where it shows the To, CC and Subject as blanks.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim rngCell     As Range

ListView41.ListItems.Clear

For Each rngCell In Worksheets("MFRs Contacts").Range("A2:A400")
    If Not rngCell = Empty Then
        With ListView41.ListItems.Add(, , rngCell.Value)
            .ListSubItems.Add , , rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .ListSubItems.Add , , rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End With
    End If
Next rngCell

End Sub

Sub ListView41_DblClick()

Dim strName     As String
Dim strEmail    As String
Dim strEmail1   As String
Dim OutApp      As Object
Dim OutMail     As Object
Dim Singlepart  As String
Dim SigString   As String
Dim Signature   As String
Dim strbody As String
Dim SigFilename

strName = ListView41.SelectedItem.Text
strEmail = ListView41.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text
strEmail1 = ListView41.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(2).Text

check = MsgBox("Send e-mail, To : " & strName & " - " & strEmail & "?" & vbNewLine & _
"CC : " & strEmail1, vbYesNo)

If check <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

Singlepart = MsgBox("For Single Part or Multiple Parts ? " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Single Part = Yes" & vbNewLine & _
"Multiple Parts = No", vbYesNo)

If Singlepart = vbYes Then

' For Single Part Numbers
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<H3><B>Dear Customer Ron de Bruin</B></H3>" & _
              "Please visit this website to download the new version.<br>" & _
              "Let me know if you have problems.<br>" & _
              "<A HREF=""http://www.rondebruin.nl/tips.htm"">Ron's Excel Page</A>" & _
              "<br><br><B>Thank you</B>"

'Signature of User
SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Rohith UTAS.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next


Userform1.Show


'With Outlook
         With OutMail
            .Display
            .To = strEmail
            .CC = strEmail1
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = strName & "_Request for Product Information"
            .HTMLBody = strbody & vbNewLine & Signature
            .Display 'or .Display if you want the user to view e-mail and send it manually
        End With

Else

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables you need to access on your form (I'm assuming strName, strEmail, and strEmail1) only have scope in `Sub ListView41_DblClick()`.  If you need to use them in your form, you'll have to pass them as parameters (my preferred way to do it) or give them global scope.

A UserForm is a class, so you can give it properties like any other class - i.e. in UserForm1:

```
Private mEmail As String

Public Property Let Email(inputVal As String)

    mEmail = inputVal

End Property

Public Property Get Email() As String

    Email = mEmail

End Property
```

Then you would call it like any other object:

```
Dim nameless_form As UserForm1

Set nameless_form = New UserForm1
nameless_form.Email = strEmail
nameless_form.Show
```